# Getting the activeLayer() in Eclipse

Tags: qgis, python, eclipse

I've been working on a plugin in python for qgis. I'm using Eclipse-pydev with remote-debug.
I believe I'm set up correctly; I've followedthe Cookbook instructions completely. When starting remote-debug, I get the blue banner with "Debugging connection activated", and Pydev Debug creates a branch named "unknown". The qgis API's path is also set in Eclipse. 
From the debug I launch :

```
from qgis.utils import iface
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print "layername:", layer.name()
```

Doing this I get the following: AttributeError:'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'activeLayer'

Of course I've made sure to actually have a layer selected before running.
This means that the connection between qgis and eclipse isn't exactly working, but I've redone the instructions a few times now and pretty sure I've completed them word for word.

Here's a screencap of the debug branchings that I get:
[image: Here's a screencap of the debug branchings that I get]

And this is the correct debug branching as shown in pydev.org/

[image: this is the correct debug branching as shown in pydev.org/]

As you can see, the correct one branches the .py file 
under 'unkown', whereas mine creates a new, probably disconnected branch.

How do I change that?